# Google Chrome window.open with name opening new window

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

So let say you have a page named `daddy` that opens a child window named `testbug`:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>daddy: Window.open bug</title>       
    </head> 
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var new_win = window.open('', "testbug", 'toolbar=1, menubar=1, status=1, left=0, top=0', true);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

If the user focuses on something other than the window with `daddy` tab and opens this page again the new `daddy` window opens up a new `testbug` child window. So now instead of having two `daddy` windows and one `testbug` window *(as is the behaviour in IE && ff)* there is two `daddy` windows and two `testbug` windows.

So my question is what do I need to keep this from happening?

**PS:** This is an internal application and is a very simple version of what we have on the real app.

---

**UPDATE**

I submitted this [issue](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=84664) to google chrome team and will wait to see their response before deciding what to do with this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only time I see a second `testbug` window being opened is if I close the `daddy` window and then reopen it. If I focus on another window and then refresh the `daddy` window, the same `testbug` window remains open.

Could you perhaps elaborate some more on which version of Chrome you are using, and your operating system? Your best bet might be to file a bug and work directly with the Chromium support team. They would be able to troubleshoot the scenario and determine if it is replicable.

Comment: A bug in chrome? I'm using chrome 11 on a win7 system. It only opens a second `testbug` window if you focus on the `testbug` window (or another seperate chrome window) and open the `daddy` window again, not a refresh. So you then have two `daddy` windows.

Comment: I've submitted it as an issue to google chrome team and we'll see what they say. I suspect that you are right and i am coding it properly ;) Maybe is a misguided security "feature"

Comment: Alright... my main point with suggesting to submit a bug report is that the Chromium team is going to know more of the gritty details of how Chrome deals with the window ID's. It isn't neccesarily a bug, but they will probably be better able to help you.

Have you heard back from them yet?

Comment: It will probably take forever for google to get to the issue i submitted so i'm just going to accept this answer in case someone else comes across the same problem.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the accept... I hope that you get somewhere with the bug report. If not, feel free to ask some more questions!! TaTa! -Crossdiver